# Question about a density funcion

Tags: probability

Let $f(x)$ be a **continuous** density function over $[0,\infty)$ with

$$\lim_{x->0}f(x)=\lim_{x->\infty}f(x)=0$$

Can we assure that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$ ?

It will be welcome some example which ilustre the answer.

Comment: Since (as indicated in the answers so far) there are obvious counterexamples, it might be worthwhile to list some of the motivating examples for your conjecture.  Maybe there are some conditions that you think are implied but remain to be stated explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Why should it? Continuos density functions do not have any special properties apart from being positive and  integrating to $1$.

So take any function that is $0$ in $0$, do whatever it wants (also assuming the value zero) and then it goes nicely to $0$ at infinity.

If it goes to infinity fast enough, this will be integrable and hence a density function

Answer (score 0):

No, consider the following:
$$f(x) = 6x(1-x), \ \forall x\in (0,1]$$
$$f(x) = 0, \ \text{elsewhere}$$

I think if you edited your question to be whether or not you can conclude $f(x) \geq 0$ then you may be correct. That being said, there is nothing interesting there since that should be implied by the fact it is a probability distribution.